# asp.net c hide/show panels inside Listview using a button (preview insert)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm trying to show the user a preview of the information they are about to insert in a ListView. I have two panels which I want to be able to show and hide using buttons inside the ListView's InsertItemTemplate.

The code I have below for the ListView is for illustrative purposes. The function is the actual code I'm using:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <InsertItemTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlInsert" runat="server" Visible="true">
            <asp:Button ID="btnPreview" runat="server" OnClick="showPreview" Text="Preview" />
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPreview" runat="server"  Visible="false">
            <p>This is the preview</p>
        </asp:Panel>

    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>


protected void showPreview(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Panel pnlInsert = (Panel)ListView1.FindControl("pnlInsert");
    pnlInsert.Visible = false;
    Panel pnlPreview = (Panel)ListView1.FindControl("pnlPreview");
    pnlPreview.Visible = true;
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

w
Looking at your code The Panels live inside the ListView called ListView1 wbut your are searching the panels inside the Parent.Controls of the ListView1

You need is ListView1.FindControl("pnlInsert) & ListView1.FindControl("pnlPreview")

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have just tried that (ammending the post accordingly) and still the same error.

Comment: @user1024416 you gave the panel id Panel1 and your searching for ListView1.FindControl("pnlInsert")

Comment: please change the name from Panel1 to pnlInsert

Comment: Amended and still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'pnlInsert', there is a 'Panel 1'.

Instead of casting controls to Panels us the `as` keyword instead . I.e

```
Panel pnlInsert = e.FindControl("pnlInsert") as Panel;
if (pnlInsert != null)
{
    //do something with pnlInsert
}
```

`ListView1.Parent.FindControl("pnlInsert")` is looking for the parent of the ListView control, then controls inside ListView. Your pnlInsert is a child of ListView.

Depending on the rest of your code you can probably just do this instead:

```
protected void showPreview(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    pnlInsert.Visible = false;
    pnlPreview.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I've tried the following based on your suggestion:

Comment: protected void showPreview(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel pnlInsert = FindControl("pnlInsert") as Panel;
        pnlInsert.Visible = false;
    }

Comment: Replace your showPreview event with the one I posted, and rename  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" as ID="pnlInsert"

Comment: Which line is throwing the null reference exception? Can you show the stack trace or error page please.

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   #########showPreview(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ###########
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Comment: hmm, can you update your question with what your showPreview method looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

The null reference exception is because either pnlInsert or plnPreview were assigned null; may be because FindControl method could not find a "pnlInsert" or "pnlPreview" controls in the ListView1.

Also I see that in the ListView1, the first panel's ID is "Panel1" and so you should change the line of code

`Panel pnlInsert = (Panel)ListView1.FindControl("pnlInsert");` to

```
Panel pnlInsert = (Panel)ListView1.FindControl("Panel1"); or
```

change the ID of the Panel in markup to "pnlInsert".

Also it is advisable to have defensive code while dealing with FindControl. Change your code to below

```
 Panel pnlInsert = ListView1.FindControl("pnlInsert") as Panel;

 if(pnlInsert != null)
 {
    pnlInsert.Visible = false;
 }
 else
 {
   // control not found - do something;
 }

 Panel pnlPreview = ListView1.FindControl("pnlPreview") as Panel;

 if(pnlPreview != null)
 {
   pnlPreview.Visible = true;
 }
 else
 {
   // control not found - do something;
 }
```

Comment: It still can't find the control:Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.